# $A\oplus B\cong A\oplus C$ implies $B\cong C$?  (No, it does not)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am asked to prove that for $p\in (1, \infty)$, $$L_{p}[0,1]\cong L_{p}[0,1]\oplus \ell_{2}$$ on a homework assignment, and I think I can show using results from class that $\ell_2\oplus \ell_2\cong \ell_2$.

From this I could say that 
$L_{p}[0,1]\oplus \ell_{2}\cong L_{p}[0,1]\oplus \ell_{2}\oplus\ell_{2}$

From here I *feel* like I should be able to conclude that 
$$L_{p}[0,1]\cong L_{p}[0,1]\oplus \ell_{2}$$

But I know of no such result that allows me to do this.  Can anyone tell me if it's true or false?

EDIT:  Definitely false.  (See counter example below from Arturo Magidin).

That is, if $B\oplus A\cong C\oplus A$ can I conclude that $B\cong C$?

Proper Solution (based on hints below from t.b.):

1) Prove that $\ell_2\oplus \ell_2\cong \ell_2$

2) Use the fact that $\ell_2$ is complemented in $L_p[0,1]$ to write $L_p[0,1] = \ell_2\oplus (\ell_2)^{c}$.

3) Then I combine these to obtain:

$L_p[0,1]\cong \ell_2\oplus (\ell_2)^{c}\cong (\ell_2\oplus \ell_2) \oplus (\ell_2)^{c} \cong \ell_2 \oplus (\ell_2\oplus (\ell_2)^{c})\cong \ell_2\oplus L_p[0,1]$.

I skipped some pieces of your more general argument.  I was just wondering if I did anything illegal, so to speak.

Comment: You say that you can prove that $\ell_2\oplus\ell_2\cong\ell_2$. Note that this means that you can prove that $\ell_2\oplus\ell_2\cong \ell_2\oplus \mathbf{0}$. If the statement you want were true, then you would be able to conclude that $\ell_2\cong \mathbf{0}$. Is **that** true?

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for putting it so simply.
I had tried many examples and they all seemed to work.  But I never thought of trying with that.

Thanks!  I feel silly now.

Comment: @David: I took the liberty of including your link in my answer since I couldn't find an online source and it's getting too late to look for the originals. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @t.b. I cited the wrong result. The right one is on page 90.

Comment: @David: thanks, I included that one.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I can't upvote the question again...

Comment: @DavidMitra:  Thanks for all the relevant info.  Our instructor proved in class that $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $L_p$ so fortunately that is available to us.  The point of this problem was probably to emphasize the importance of that fact.

Comment: @BenjaminLim:  Just curious.  In that example, isn't $(y-axis)\cong (line: y = x)$?

Comment: @t.b. Sorry I got confused between the two spaces being equal and them being isomorphic.

Comment: Well, in any case there's no problem because my claim was false anyway.  :)

Comment: Would you mind making it a bit clearer that my hint solved your problem? It looks a bit silly to give a hint to a complete solution...

Comment: Wouldn't this work: $$L_p\cong \ell_2\oplus Y\cong ( \ell_2\oplus\ell_2)\oplus Y\cong  \ell_2\oplus(\ell_2 \oplus Y)\cong  \ell_2\oplus L_p,$$  or, is this just t.b.'s argument? (it's late for me...)

Comment: @David: that's even better...

Comment: To address your general question about whether direct decompositions are unique (i.e. whether $B \cong C$ in your case), you might also consider the very small/simple counter-example of Bjarni Jonsson described [here.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45668/is-the-decomposition-of-an-algebra-into-irreducible-components-essentially-unique/46310#46310).  This is discussed at length in [Algebras, Lattices, Varieties](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebras_lattices_varieties.html?id=_PnuAAAAMAAJ) chapter 5.

Comment: Your added argument looks fine (though you have an extra "$\oplus$" in item 1.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Arturo explained why your idea doesn't work, here's a

**Hint:**

Let $X = L^p$ and let $Y = L^p \oplus \ell^2$.

Prove:

2. $X^2 \cong X$ and $Y^2 \cong Y$.
3. $X$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $Y$ and vice versa (you probably know that $L^p$ has a complemented subspace isomorphic to $\ell^2$, see e.g. Proposition 6.4.2 in [Albiac-Kalton](http://books.google.com/books?id=vjOBcgAACAAJ) or follow David Mitra's suggestion, Corollary 9.2 on  page 90 in Carother's *[A Short Course on Banach Space Theory](http://books.google.ch/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&pg=PA90)*).
4. Now you are in position to apply Pełczyński's argument to conclude that $X \cong Y$ (see point 3. of my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110438/is-there-an-explicit-isomorphism-between-l-infty0-1-and-ell-infty) for the details).

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  I love it.  Thanks.  The $X^2\cong X$ I hadn't thought of doing, although I literally did it for $X:=C[0,1]$ when I was trying to test my original (but false) claim.

Thanks again!

Comment: I included my argument into my original question.  I didn't really follow your process exactly, but just used the argument in your referenced post about $L_\infty$.  Does my argument still work?  Or am I misunderstanding a key concept? 

edit: (just saw you comment above.  Thanks very much again!!!)

Comment: That's why I wrote: yes, that's it! (that was directed at you) :)