# Which kind of additivity for measures is more natural

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

To start with, I have almost no any experience in the theory of *finitely* additive (f.a.) measures, but I work a bit with *countably* additive (c.a.) ones and find the theory in the latter case amazingly beautiful. My concern is that at the moment measures have been introduced as an extension of such notions as area and volume, I can understand that the additivity property came alone naturally. However, I believe, that at that moment the choice f.a. vs. c.a. might not have any strong arguments. Later, it appeared that in many cases the space of c.a. (but not f.a.) measures is the dual of a corresponding space of all bounded continuous functions. Since the latter is a pretty "natural" object, I would say that its dual is "natural" as well. Would it be right to say that c.a. measures are more "natural" than f.a. ones, or that it appeared to be more successful/useful, and if so - why do we need the f.a. measures?

I hope, that a bit loose formulation of the question still allows for an answer.

Comment: The space of (signed) finitely additive measures is the dual of the space of bounded measurable functions, so the "duality argument" doesn't seem to be particularly convincing.

Comment: @Martin: that I didn't know, thanks for pointing it out. So does it mean, that for any c.a. measure there an f.a. measure such that their integrals agree on all continuous functions?

Comment: Th dual space of $\ell_\infty$ is a space of complex valued finitely additive measures denoted by $ba$. Since $\ell_\infty=\ell_1^*$, then we have natural embedding $\ell_1\hookrightarrow ba$. So the question is whether $ba=\ell_1$, or in other words what are finitely additive but not countable additive measures on $\mathbb{N}$. It turns out that question depends on axiom of choice.

Comment: For [certain axiomatizations](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/110983/19538) we can have $\ell_\infty^*=\ell_1$, so there will not be "purely" finitely additive measures. Since this measures affiliated with "choice" their usage could be non-constructve. This is one of the reasons why we prefer countably additive mesures.

Comment: Without finitely (but not countably) additive  measures we would not have infinite [amenable groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group), which would seem like a loss, given the Wikipedia list of the properties equivalent to amenability.