# Explicit isomorphism between $L^\infty[0,1]$ and its hyperplanes

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, axiom-of-choice

The Banach space $L^\infty[0,1]$ is isomorphic to all its hyperplanes (closed linear subspaces of codimension one). One way of seeing this is the following:

1. all hyperplanes of a Banach space are mutually isomorphic
2. $\ell_\infty$ is isomorphic to its hyperplane $\{x\in\ell_\infty\colon x(1)=0\}$.
3. $L^\infty[0,1]$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$.

In the above list the step (2) can be made explicit. On the other hand, the third item (3) cannot; see [this question and its answer by](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110438/296126) [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel).

Is there a direct way of proving the above statement which allows for an explicit construction?

In particular, I would be interested in an answer to the question of whether it is possible to construct an explicit isomorphism between $L^\infty[0,1]$ and its hyperplane $\{f\in L^\infty[0,1]\colon \int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0\}$. This question is related to [this question on mathoverlow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126383/on-hyperplanes-of-l-infty).

Comment: How do you define a hyperplane in this case?

Comment: @AsafKaragila linear subspace of codimension one

Comment: Also, when you say "isomorphism", do you mean as vector spaces, or as Banach spaces (i.e. a linear isometry, or a linear homeomorphism, or what?) Because the only way I immediately see why (1) is true, is by appealing to Hahn–Banach, which also uses choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean linear homeomorphism and you are right - the standard proof of this step needs Hahn-Banach, I will fix this part of the question

Comment: I suppose then that you want to define a hyperplane as a *closed* linear subspace of codimension one?

Comment: @NateEldredge: yes, of course. I am sorry for creating such a chaos in the comments.