# How to prove that the $L^p$ spaces are infinite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

It is well-known that (given a measure space $(S,\mathcal A,\mu)$ and $1\le p\le\infty$) the Banach space $L^p(S,\mathcal A,\mu)$ has infinite dimension.

Is there an easy way to proof this statement (or a suitable reference (preferably a book) where I can find this result)?

Comment: if $\mathcal{A}$ is finite, you can't prove it. Otherwise consider indicator functions of all measurable sets

Comment: You can find necessary and sufficient conditions for finite-dimensionality [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/151015/5363) (in case $\mu$ is totally finite --- remember that $L^p \subset L^1$ under this assumption). @Norbert: it also depends on the measure...

Comment: You are also in trouble if $\mu = 0$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Norbert mentioned, this is simply not true if $S$ is finite.

In general, suppose you can find a collection of countably infinite pairwise disjoint measurable sets $\{ A_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, each with finite positive measure.  Then, the collection $\{ 1_{A_n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an infinite linearly independent set contained in $L^p$.  Why?  First of all, the fact that each $A_k$ has finite measure guarantees that $1_{A_k}$ is an element of $L^p$.  As for linear independence, suppose we have some finite linear combination of these functions that is equal to $0$:
$$
a_11_{A_{n_1}}+\cdots +a_m1_{A_{n_m}}=0.
$$
Now, multiply this equation by $1_{A_{n_k}}$ and integrate.  You will find that
$$
a_k\mu (A_{n_k})=0,
$$
and hence, because $\mu (A_{n_k})>0$, we have that $a_k=0$, which proves linear independence.

Answer (score 4):

Since $l^{p}$ embeds isomorphically into $L^{p}$,and it's easy to check that $l^{p}$ is infinitive dimensional.