# $L^p $ is not uniformly convex for $p=1, \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

As the title says: how can we prove that $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ is not uniformly convex for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$.

> Does anyone knows a counter-example for the cases $ p=1$ and $ p =
>  \infty$ for the space $L^p( \mathbb R^n)$ ?

I am studying N.L. Carothers book "A short course to Banach space theory".

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p=\infty$ and $n=2$, consider $\mathbf{x}=(1,1)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(0,1)$.

You might also make use of the fact that [uniformly convex Banach spaces are reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milman%E2%80%93Pettis_theorem).

**Edit:** As I was typing up a more detailed answer, I found the [*first comment* to this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151135/52893), which puts things more succinctly than I was going to do (and saves me a bit of typing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I think there is some misunderesttod about the notation. $L^p$ is the space of lebesgue measurable functions raied in $p-\text{th}$ power, not the space of seequences.

Comment: Even so, the $L^p$ spaces you mention have two-dimensional subspaces isometric to this $2$-dimensional $l^p$ space.  And if the subspace is not uniformly convex, certainly the whole space is not either.