# Exercise in Hahn-Banach Theorem; Finding linear functional $-p(-x)\leq f(x)\leq p(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

(The following exercises are in
Kreyszig's book 218 page; EXE 10) I want to solve the following
exercise : If $X=l^\infty$, let $p(x)=\lim\sup x_i $, which is
sublinear. Then find a linear functional $f(x)$ s.t. $$ -p(-x)\leq
f(x) \leq p(x)$$

**Background** : If $p$ is a sublinear function on
a real vector space, i.e.,
$$ p(x+y)\leq p(x) + p(y),\ p(cx)=cp(x),\ c\geq 0 $$

then there exists linear functional $f$ s.t. $$ -p(-x)\leq f(x) \leq
p(x) $$

**Proof** : By Hahn-Banach theorem we have $f(x)\leq p(x)
$ so that $$ f(-x)\leq p(-x)$$

That is $$ -p(-x)\leq f(x) \leq f(x)$$

Now, we return to original question : $X=l^\infty$, let
$p(x)=\limsup x_i $. So
$$-p(-x)=-\limsup (-x_i)=\liminf x_i$$ Hence if such functional $f$ exists, then
$f(x)=\lim x_i$ when $\lim x_i$ exists. If $x_{2i+1}=2,\ x_{2i}=1$
then $v_{2i+1}=1,\ v_{2i}=2$ then $ f(x+v)=3 $. That is, the problem
is how determine $f$ on $x$ where $\lim x_i$ does not exist.

**Try** : If we let $f(x)=\frac{\lim\inf x_i + \lim\sup x_i}{2} $, then note
that $f(x+v)\neq f(x)+f(v)$. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the exercise is expecting you to do exactly what you did - to prove that there *exists* a functional with the given properties. (Not to explicitly write down such $f$.)

You can notice that in this way you get a functional $f\in \ell_\infty^* \setminus \ell_1$. (A few proofs of the fact that $\ell_\infty^*\ne\ell_1$ are also collected here: [Dual of $l^\infty$ is not $l^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868787).) Existence of such functional cannot be proved in ZF, so any proof has to use some non-constructive step at some point. Some posts where the fact that this is not provable in ZF is mentioned: [Nonnegative linear functionals over $l^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55651) and [$\ell^1$ vs. continuous dual of $\ell^{\infty}$ in ZF+AD](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103476).